# Nothing inserted in database using $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, session

I have the following example usage:

```
  $insert = "
  INSERT INTO table (
      field
  ) VALUES (
      '".$_SESSION['field']."'
  )
  ";
```

For some reason it's inserting blanks and no data is being submitted. Is what I am doing the right way?

I do have multiple fields but they were too many so just shrunk the example to include only one field.

Comment: Did you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) before the statement?

Comment: have you initiated the session using session_start()

Comment: oops my bad.  forgot.  now after the form is submitted how can i end the session?

Comment: You should escape the variable with mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Well, obviously your variable `$_SESSION['field']` does not contain a value that would not be converted into an empty string.

Comment: @briedis this is what i am using:  $_SESSION['q1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q1']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session_start() for starting the session before assigning anything to $_SESSION['field'].

After insertion you can delete session variables but not the session itself using session_unset(), or you can destroy the variables using session_destroy().